# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat

Tags: java, image

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.IOException: The byte
>   array is not a recognized imageformat.

I am getting this error when I am running the `jrxml` file that contain images in jasper. I have changed the version of the `itext` also in `pom.xml` file. but its still not working, Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I was trying to fetch the image from the `classpath`, and I was using the same object for creating two diff PDF by changing some values. I used `FileInputStream` to read the image. This error occurred because we can't reuse `InputStream` in Java.

Comment: My problem was using the same ```InputStream``` twice either. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Helpfull comment above, when you use the Inputstream one time, you cannot use this in a second time on the same context jrxml, the resource will be closed by the tag <imageExpression>

Answer (score -2):

This can solve the problem:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```